# How to measure time overhead related to virtual methods call in embedded C++ software?

Tags: c++, performance, methods, time, embedded

Let's say I have a C++ code intended for an embedded application. The code contains bunch of virtual method calls (please don't speculate whether it is correct or not). I would like to know the time overhead related to the virtual methods calling. The reason why I am interested in that is because the virtual methods are called also from an interrupt service routine which is invoked with 50 microseconds period and at the time being the program execution consumes 24 microseconds. I would like to know whether I can save some significant amount of time in case I won't use the virtual methods.

My first idea how to do that was to add some code which will activate some gpio pin before calling one selected virtual method and then deactive the gpio pin immediately after entering the selected virtual method. Then I can measure duration of the pulse occuring at the gpio pin via oscilloscope. That time should correspond to the virtual method related time overhead. The time measurement is coupled with only one virtual method and I am not sure whether I can say that the time overhead will be equal for all of the virtual methods.

Does anybody know any better approach for measuring the time overhead related to
the virtual methods call in embedded environment? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: If you have a simulator for the target's processor, you can ask it about the clock cycles spent so far. But another option is to follow the code on machine instruction level in a debugger/simulator and compare the differences between virtual and non-virtual calls. -- Anyway, why is this overhead relevant?

Comment: Your definition of "overhead" seems off. An overhead has to be compared to a baseline. Assuming you have an answer to the "how to time" part and you get, say, 50ns as a result, then you are still not better informed if you do not have another approach to compare it too.

Comment: @spectras thank you for your reaction. I have just attempted to append the background related to my question.

Comment: To detail my point: the virtual call does not happen in the void, it has a purpose. To measure overhead you need to know what you would replace it with, which depends on the reason you use it for. Could you replace it with a regular call? With a function pointer? With branches to pick among 2 or 3 functions? With compile-time polymorphism? Those have different performance tradeoffs, and cover different use cases. Furthermore, the compiler might be clever enough to swap between some approaches if it can prove they behave the same in a specific context but one should perform better.

Comment: …thus there is not really any substitute for measuring (the whole code block, not just one call), implementing the alternative approach and measuring again.

Comment: You already answered this yourself. Using an oscilloscope is the superior benchmarking method. However, if you set a pin upon entering the ISR and clear it upon leaving, you do miss measuring the interrupt call overhead. It should be a fixed number though, which you can determine by reading the core manual for the specific part. Also keep in mind that GPIO could have relatively slow rising/falling timing, check analog characteristics of the port used.

Comment: @Lundin thank you for your reaction. Do you think that I can say that the time overhead will be the same for all the virtual method calls or is it possible that there will be some differences between them?

Comment: It is likely to be deterministic, but possible that some virtual calls might be optimised out in some usage patterns - it is implementation dependent (and possibly compile option dependent).  Nonetheless you are probably sweating the small stuff. Function call overhead is typically only an issue when it is cumulative.  To that end a simpler and more useful test perhaps is to call a function many times so you can time it cumulatively with software, and compare a virtual with an otherwise identical non-virtual function and check the generated code to ensure it is not optimised out.

Comment: @Steve Functions with more parameters will have longer overhead, naturally. Anyway, the main issue here is that a program with a perioding 50us interrupt won't have much time to do anything else but serving that interrupt. So there will be just so many functions.

Comment: If time is that critical, (and 50% time in the ISR context at 50us rate would suggest that it is), you would probably avoid anything that adds overhead to the ISR - any function call virtual or otherwise, and any non-static, non-inline C++ member function calls in any case.  In-lining removes all function call overhead.  I would question a design that needs such an interrupt rate and ISR CPU load - that is likely a better route to an optimal implementation than considering function call overhead - if that is the issue you are already in trouble.

Comment: Can't you write a microbenchmark to call the same code 10^7 times, with and without the virtual call? Also good to analyze the generated assembly and to know the timing characteristics of dynamic branches in the given CPU.